# how to add an array to an integer c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a c# code which gets students grades with jagged array (the number of grades can be different in each student) and calculate the average for each student . here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace students_avg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            int n,m,i,j,count=0,avg;
            Console.WriteLine("please enter the number of students");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int [][] student = new int [n+1][];
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("how many grades does student number " + i + "have?");
                m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                student[i] = new int[m];
                Console.WriteLine("please enter student number " + i + "'s grades");
                for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    student[i] =new int[] {Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())};
                    count +=Convert.ToInt32(student[i]);              
                }
                avg = count / m ;
                Console.WriteLine("the student number " + i + "'s average is " + avg);          
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

but I have problem because it doesn't give me the proper avg. So how can I add the student's grades in the correct way?

Comment: Any particular reason for trying to hand ball arrays when you can just use List of lists and get all this via linq?

Comment: You set `student[i] =new... ` outside the loop and on each execution of the loop, yet make no use of `j` in the loop. `Convert.ToInt32(student[i])` is passing the inner array as an object, which I would think should throw an exception as  int[] isn't `IConvertible`.  I Think you mean `student[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); count += student[i][j];` No need to call Convert on the second line when we already know the value is an `int`.  You probably should use `int.Parse()` or even better `int.TryParse()` so you might handle bad input.

Comment: No need to declare your loop variables at the top of the method.  They should be scoped to the loop condition.  Also give your other variables meaningful names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using jagged arrays is a requirement for your task, so I'll stick to OP. If it's not, you could use `List<List<int>>` for the grades as Mark suggested.

I tried to do minimal change in your code.

The thing is, you were missing declaring the "jagged" part of your array and while trying to add to total count, you were having a little bit of an issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n, m, i, j, count;

    Console.WriteLine("please enter the number of students");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[][] student = new int[n][];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("how many grades does student number " + (i+1) + "      have?");
        m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        student[i] = new int[m];
        Console.WriteLine("please enter student number " + (i+1) + "'s grades");
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            student[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            count += Convert.ToInt32(student[i][j]);
        }
        var avg = count / m;
        Console.WriteLine("the student number " + i + "'s average is " + avg);

    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful

Comment: @SaraMolavi You are welcome. Guess I forgot adding `+1` while showing average. You might need to change that. I also suggest you to take a look at Dmitry's answer as well, for the purpose of learning, as it includes both Linq and String Interpolation topics.

Comment: you might also set avg to zero after printing the value

Comment: Not really, it's in the scope of outer for and will be redeclared for student i+1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
int n,m,i,j,count=0,avg;
```

to:

```
int n,m,i,j,count=0;
double avg;
```

and this line:

```
avg = count / m ;
```

to

```
avg = (double)count / (double)m ;
count=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also: you're creating a new grade array for every grade input here

```
student[i] =new int[] {Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())};
```

That line should be

```
student[i][j-1] =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Second:

```
count +=Convert.ToInt32(student[i]);
```

Should be

```
count += student[i][j-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code try now

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n, m, i, j, count = 0, avg;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter the number of students");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[][] student = new int[n + 1][];
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how many grades does student number " + i + "      have?");
            m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            student[i] = new int[m+1];
            Console.WriteLine("please enter student number " + i + "'s grades");
            for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                student[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                count += Convert.ToInt32(student[i][j]);
            }
            avg = count / m;
            Console.WriteLine("the student number " + i + "'s average is " + avg);
            avg = 0;
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```